# How to get information from a div that is only available after the page loads with php?

Tags: php, html

I'm looking to get information from an external website, by taking it from a div in their code. But using the file_get_contents() method doesn't work because the information isn't in the source code for the page. It only shows up after the page loads (It's available if you use an inspect element in the web browser).

Is there a way to do this? Or Am I just out of luck on that?

Comment: 2 options. 1> Use a headless browser with js support (eg phantomJS), 2> manually work out where the data is coming from (hint, its some javascript), and write a parser that gets the info from source